# How to confirm the swagger version being used in my API?

Tags: rest, jersey, swagger

I have integrated my REST API (developed on Jersey) with swagger 2.0
But when I see the Json listing, it shows me the following entries :

```
"apiVersion": "1.0.0",
"swaggerVersion": "1.2",
```

The swaggerVerison is listed to be 1.2, shouldn't it be 2.0 ? 
How can I confirm that my API is using the swagger 2.0 ?

Due to some specific requirement, I must be using the 2.0 version of swagger, and after a lot of googling I'm not able to confirm this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think you integrated with Swagger 2.0?

Comment: I downloaded the swagger UI files from [link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/v2.0.24) the repo is tagged as version 2.0, but as far as swagger jars are concerned, I couldn't find maven dependencies listed as version 2.0 or more. The artifactId of the swagger core I used is swagger-core_2.10, but the version is listed as 1.3.2

Comment: One has nothing to do with the other. If you want to get Swagger 2.0 specification, you need to use swagger-core 1.5.1-M2. The information is found in swagger-core's repository.

Comment: Thanks @Ron for the prompt reply. I just found that, and I am now trying the 1.5.x version of swagger-core, and I also found that I need to use swagger-jersey2-jaxrs (jersey2 version) as the jersey1 doesn't include all the requisite classes that were being used in my rest service.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be confusing between Swagger Core and Swagger UI.

The version 2.0 that you mentioned from github is the version of Swagger UI.

swaggerVersion 1.2 is the version of Swagger Core itself.